# How to understand the compactification of the upper half plane as motivation for Gromov compactification of an arbitrary $\delta$-hyperbolic space??

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, compactification, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces, gromov-boundary

Let $X$ be a $\delta$-hyperbolic space. Let us define an equivalence relation on geodesic rays $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 :[0,\infty) \rightarrow X$ by {$\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2\,\, \iff d(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)) < \infty\}$. The Gromov boundary $\partial X$ is defined as the set of all equivalence classes of geodesic rays in $X$.

Consider the upper half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : im(z)>0\}$ equipped with the hyperbolic metric. I have to first show that its Gromov boundary $\partial \mathbb{H}$ is homemorphic to the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$, and also show that we can impose a topology on $\bar{\mathbb{H}} = \mathbb{H} \cup \partial \mathbb{H}$ such that $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$ is compact under this topology.

In the textbook, [Geometric Group Theory](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/ggt.pdf), by Cornelia Druţu and Michael Kapovich, the basis for the topology on $\bar{X} = X \cup \partial X$, where $X$ is a $\delta$-hyperbolic geodesic space is defined as consisting of metric balls $B(z,r)$ for $z \in X$, and neighbourhoods $U_{x,y}(\xi)=\{z \in \bar{X} : [xz] \cap B(y,k) \neq \phi\}$, where $[xz]$ is any geodesic ray joining $x$ to $z$, $y$ is a point on a geodesic ray joining $x$ to $\xi$, $k > 3\delta$, and $\xi \in \partial X$.

In the textbook [A Primer on Mapping Class Groups](http://euclid.nmu.edu/%7Ejoshthom/Teaching/MA589/farbmarg.pdf), $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$ is topologized by the basis consisting of: the usual open sets of ${\mathbb{H}}$ plus one open set $U_P$ for each open half-plane $P$ in ${\mathbb{H}}$. A point of ${\mathbb{H}}$ lies in $U_P$ if it lies in $P$ and a point of $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$ lies in $U_P$ if every representative ray $\gamma(t)$ eventually lies in $P$.

I have understood how the Gromov boundary of $\mathbb{H}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$, and also understood how an arbitrary hyperbolic space $X$ can be compactified to get $\bar{X}$ with the topology defined above, but I cannot understand the compactification of $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$ with the respective topology and also how this serves as motivation for the general case.

Would appreciate some ideas to push me in the right direction.

Comment: "I cannot understand" is not a question but a statement. Did you try to work out a homeomorpism from the Gromov compactification of the hyperbolic plane to the closed unit disk? Did you at least get a bijection?

Comment: The hyperbolic upper half plane is homeomorphic to the open unit disk, and this can be shown by using a suitable Mobius transformation, but I am not able to find a mapping that shows the closure of the upper half plane is homemorphic to the closed unit disk with respect to the Up topology mentioned above.

Comment: Well, there is an obvious map sending each hyperbolic geodesic ray to its "end-point" in the boundary circle (assuming that you are working in the unit disk model). Try to analyze this map and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

You are leaving out one very important feature of $\mathbb H$, namely the Morse lemma, which says (with quantifiers inserted properly): every quasigeodesic has finite Hausdorff distance from a geodesic.

This applies in particular to quasigeodesic rays: every quasigeodesic ray in $\mathbb H$ has finite Hausdorff distance from a geodesic ray. Furthermore, two geodesic rays in $\mathbb H$ that have finite Hausdorff distance are equivalent and hence represent the same point in $\partial\mathbb H$.

It follows that the equivalence relation on geodesic rays that defines $\partial\mathbb H$ can be widened to obtain an equivalence relation on quasigeodesic rays --- namely, finite Hausdorff distance --- which *still* defines $\partial\mathbb H$.

This fact is useful in studying the large scale geometry of $\mathbb H$. For example, you can use geodesic rays to prove that an isometry of $\mathbb H$ induces a homeomorphism of $\partial\mathbb H$. But in the proof of Mostow rigidity you need more: in one of the first steps of that proof, one uses the quasigeodesic ray definition of $\partial\mathbb H$ and the Morse Lemma to prove that a quasi-isometry of $\mathbb H$ induces a homeomorphism of $\partial\mathbb H$. One might summarize this by saying that Gromov's definition of $\partial\mathbb H$ --- namely, the quasigeodesic ray definition --- is more robust, i.e. it is applicable in broader situations than the geodesic ray definition.

And in the general study of $\delta$-hyperbolic spaces $X$, the Morse lemma is still true, providing a robust, "quasigeodesic ray" definition of $\partial X$, which is behind pretty much everything in our understanding of $\partial X$.